# Using Multiple setIntervals?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to use two (or more) setIntervals that bounces back and forth turning on/off the 2 functions. I also tried clearInterval() but I'm getting same or no results. Please help, I've been trying to figure out since morning its driving me insane!! :'( How do I properly use multiple setIntervals? If it's not too much to ask, some very simple examples would be great! (I'm very new).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>PreLicenseTraining T-Idler</title>
</head>
<body onload="f1();">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function f1() {
            document.write("1");
            setInterval(f2, 1000);
        }
        function f2() {
            document.write("2");
            setInterval(f1, 1000);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Output:

(First Second) 1
(Second Second) 12
(Third Second) 1221
(Fourth Second) 12211221

All I want is a simple 1212121 with every second.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. http://jsfiddle.net/aWtyw/

Comment: Oh wow.. how embarrassing T_T I used setTimeout before idk why I stopped after 1 attempt.. It works beautifully thank you :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to store the timer you are creating, this is how you would use `setInterval` however, I would also recommend as [Crazy Train](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437417/crazy-train) said to use `setTimeout`.

**JS:**

```
<body onload="f1();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timer1, timer2;

        function f1() {
            document.write("1");
            timer1 = setInterval(f2, 1000);

            if (timer2 != undefined) clearInterval(timer2);
        }

        function f2() {
            document.write("2");
            timer2 = setInterval(f1, 1000);

            if (timer1 != undefined) clearInterval(timer1);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```